# IndexedDB result sometimes corrupt

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, localforage

I'm using "localforage" in a project and have a mysterious problem.
Through redux / immutableJS I'm storing some settings like "locale", reading it from storage sometimes works but often not.

I hooked into localeforages query system:

```
var store = transaction.objectStore(self._dbInfo.storeName);
var req = store.get(key);
req.onsuccess = function() {
    var value = req.result;
    console.log(value);
    // ...
}
```

This should output the plain, serialized immutable data string:

```
"[\"~#iM\",[\"locale\",\"de_DE\"]]"
```

But very often I instead receive this:

```
"[\"~#iM\",[\"locale\",null]]"
```

When the error occurs the Developer Tools' "application" tab is showing the correct value (so not NULL).
Same codebase, absolutely NO CHANGES, shows different behavior in current Chrome (never working) and Firefox (sometimes working).

Anyone got a similar error in the past?
I don't understand how a plain string value could sometimes work and sometimes not.